# Подсчет по месяцам

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть таблица расходов в Google Sheets, в ней два столбика:

- сумма (столбец C числовой формат)
- дата (столбец D "11.12.2018")

Необходимо суммировать расходы по месяцам.

Пытаюсь использовать функцию `SUMIF`: `SUMIF(D:D;Условие;C:C)`. Вся проблема с этим самым условием. Если поставить в условие конкретный день 
в кавычках, например "11.12.2018", то все работает, сумма за день считается. А это говорит о том что формула воспринимает дату как строку и сравнивает ее со строкой. И вроде как на место строки можно поставить шаблон. Но! если я вместо "11.12.2018" ставлю в формулу "??.12.2018" или "*.12.2018" чтобы найти сумму за декабрь подсчет дает 0.

Буду признателен за подсказку.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте пример для точного понимания задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко, то

```
=SUMIF(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(D2:D;"DD.MM.YYYY"));"*12.2018";C2:C)
```

### `SUMIF`

Сумма по заданному числу. Положим, что в `L1` находится некая дата, тогда мы можем посчитать сумму за эту дату

```
=SUMIF(
  ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(D2:D33)&YEAR(D2:D33));
  MONTH(L1)&YEAR(L1);
  C2:C
)
```

Аналогично первому, но с преобразованием формата

```
=SUMIF(
  ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(D2:D;"MMYYYY"));
  TEXT(L1;"MMYYYY");
  C2:C
)
```

Часто требуется вывести результат непосредственно напротив нужной строки, тогда лучше использовать комбинацию `ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF)`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
 LEN(C2:C);
 SUMIF(MONTH(D2:D);MONTH(D2:D);C2:C);
 ""
))
```

### `SUMIFS`

Аналогичными свойствами обладает функция `SUMIFS`. Будет работать как для дат, так и для преобразования в текст:

```
=SUMIFS(
  C2:C33;
  ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(D2:D33)&YEAR(D2:D33));
  MONTH(L1)&YEAR(L1)
)
```

### `SUMPRODUCT`

Технически, именно решение на базе `SUMPRODUCT` должно возглавлять список и являться основным решением, т.к. эта формула является олицетворением смысла табличных процессоров

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(D2:D)=YEAR(L1))*(MONTH(D2:D)=MONTH(L1))*C2:C)
```

### `QUERY`

Одним из самых распространенных вариантов является использование функции `QUERY`.

Например,

```
=QUERY(
  ARRAYFORMULA({TEXT(D2:D;"YYYY-MM")\C2:C});
  "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1<>'1899-12' " &
  "group by Col1 label Col1'Дата',sum(Col2)'Сумма'"
)
```

### `FILTER`

Мощнейшая функция в Таблицах. Если дата все еще в `L1`, то

```
=SUM(FILTER(C2:C33;MONTH(D2:D33)=MONTH(L1)))
```

Предпочитаемый мной вариант

```
=SUM(FILTER(C2:C33;TEXT(D2:D33;"MMYYYY")=TEXT(L1;"MMYYYY")))
```

[Примеры в Таблице](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vrJ0R55vH8eud7OsUF8ZoAjrj7O_7UZ9A43ksKKv56M/edit?usp=sharing)

### Примечание

Вы всегда должны помнить, что месяца год от года могут повторяться, и, если данные находятся в диапазоне разных лет, это стоит учесть.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ваш прекрасно иллюстрированный ответ. Пока не все понял, а именно QUERRY, но то что ARRAYFORMULA мне подойдет я уже понял, сейчас буду проверять.

Comment: [Как отблагодарить за ответ на Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7124/178725)